# sympy Matrices not aligned

Tags: python, math, matrix, sympy

I'm trying to use sympy to help me isolate a vector in a matrix expression. I have written this code:

```
    import sympy
    from sympy import symbols, MatrixSymbol, Matrix
    from sympy import Identity    

    Xp = MatrixSymbol('Xp', 3,1)
    t = MatrixSymbol('t', 3,1)
    n = MatrixSymbol('n', 3,1)
    H = n.T*Xp*Identity(3) - t*n.T
```

my intention is to isolate n. I'm not sure if sympy can do that, but I already get a 'ShapeError: Matrices n'*Xp and I are not aligned', I think this error should not happen as n'*Xp is a scalar so it should be able to multiply with a matrix.

How can I get the expression `n.T*Xp*Identity(3)` to be valid?
and, can sympy help me to isolate the vector n in this equation?

Answer (score 1):

```
n.T*Xp*Identity(3)
```

has the dimension signature

```
(1,3)*(3,1)*(3,3)
```

which obviously will not work.

```
n*Xp.T*Identity(3)
```

could work.

---

If you want to solve

```
H=(n.T*X)*I-t*n.T
```

for `n` then the first remark is that this is not always possible. Assuming that a solution exists, remark that

```
1/(t.T*t)*t.T*H=1/(t.T*t)*(n.T*X)*t.T-n.T
```

so that

```
n = a*t - b*H.T*t
```

where `a` is unknown and `b=1/(t.T*t)`. Inserting into the original equation gives

```
H = (a*t.T*X-b*t.T*H*X)*I - a*t*t.T + b*t*t.T*H
```

or

```
H - b*t*t.T*H +b*(t.T*H*X)*I = a*((t.T*X)*I - t*t.T)
```

which in each non-trivial component of the right side matrix will give a value of `a`, but a solution only exists if all those values are the same.

Comment: `n.T*Xp` is a (1,1) matrix, which I assume sympy can interpret as a scalar. is there a conversion function that I can use to force this? then is a scalar matrix multiplication. Notice that it doesn't work even if I put parentheses around `n.T*Xp`

Comment: This matlab convention is a can of worms. I think that even as 1×1 matrix it still is a matrix object, you would need something like the Kronecker product to get this multiplication right. Or perhaps `(n.T*Xp)[0,0]` works.

Comment: Ok, thanks. if I write `H = (n.T*Xp)[0,0]*Identity(3)  - t*n.T` it works. I'd like to solve for n now. I've tried solve(H, n) but it complains 'str' object has no attribute 'is_Piecewise'??

Comment: Such a solution will most likely not exist, I've added a section about that. You might want to look for the smallest error solution.

Comment: Solving matrix expressions currently doesn't work, unless you replace the matrix expressions with noncommutative symbols first. See https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/7379.